# itext color for cell data

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using itexsharp to create PDF and have a table with header and rows. I can give colors to my header, but when i add colors to my rows(cell) i cant do that.
how can I give colors to my rows.

example:

```
 ..................
:Header1 : Header2 :  //I have a sytle here allreadey
 ...................
:Row1    : Row2    : //I want to add style here?
....................
```

code:

```
private String WritePDF(DataTable dt)
        {
            String fileName = "";  

            //Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
            PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(m_PDFColumnCount);

            pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 1;
            pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
            pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
           // pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;
           //194 214 155


            this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "date");
            this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "time");
            this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "result");
            this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "fullname");
            this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "regarding");            




            //Adding DataRow
                for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < dt.Rows.Count; intIndex++)
                {

                    dt.Rows[intIndex]["details"] = getplaintext(dt.Rows[intIndex]["details"].ToString());


                  //Font verdana = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10, new Color(125, 88, 15));
                  //cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(51, 102, 102);


                  pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["date"].ToString());
                  pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["time"].ToString());
                  pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["result"].ToString());
                  pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["fullname"].ToString());
                  pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["regarding"].ToString());

                  PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Rows[intIndex]["details"].ToString()));
                  cell.Colspan = 5;
                  pdfTable.AddCell(cell);


                }

            String folderPath = "C:\\PDFs\\"; //should be in configfile.

            fileName =  String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",folderPath, dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString(),".pdf" );

            //Exporting to PDF

            if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
            }
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate ))
            {
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);               
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }

            return fileName;

        }

        private void BuildPDFHeader( PdfPTable pdfTable, String strText)
        {
              PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(strText)); 
                    cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(51, 102,102);
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your header row, you are creating the `PdfPCell` objects yourself:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(strText)); 
cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(51, 102,102);
```

For the rest of the rows, you are asking iTextSharp to create the `PdfPCell` objects:

```
pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["date"].ToString());
```

This is a `string`: `dt.Rows[intIndex]["date"].ToString()`

iText will create a `PdfPCell` the same way you did when creating the `PdfPCell` objects for the header, so one option is that you create the `PdfPCell` objects for the other rows the same way:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Rows[intIndex]["date"].ToString())); 
cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(60, 60, 60);
pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
```

However, there is a short cut. You can define the background color for the *default cell*:

```
pdfTable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(60, 60, 60);
```

Now, the background color of each cell that you add as a `string` with the `addCell()` method will have the background color of the default cell.

**Important:** I see that you are using an obsolete version of iTextSharp that is 6 years old: you are using the `Color` class instead of `BaseColor`. Please be aware that there are technical and legal issues with that version. Please upgrade to a more recent version.