# IText background color for cell data

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using itextsharp to create PDF and I have data in three rows. I can set the background color of the piece of text but what I need is to give the background color to the whole area according to text in different rows.
I found the solution to do the same by adding tables but when I add the table, my table is not visible in the document.

Can anyone share the full code to add Table then cell with content and background color?
here is my code:

```
float width = 85.6063f;
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(width, tempHeight);
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
}
Document document = null;
PdfWriter writer = null;
document = new Document(pageSize, 4, 4, 0, 5);

writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
document.Open();
PdfPCell myCell;
iTextSharp.text.Font font1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, BaseColor.BLACK);
myCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("hi", font1));
PdfPTable myTable = new PdfPTable(2);

PdfPCell cellTest = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is a test document"));
cellTest.BackgroundColor=new BaseColor(255,0,0);
myTable.AddCell(cellTest);

document.Add(myTable);
Paragraph welcomeParagraph = new Paragraph("Hello, World");

document.Add(welcomeParagraph);
string BinPath = Server.MapPath("~");
String strAppPath = BinPath;
float fontSize = 5;

BaseFont bfnimodmt = BaseFont.CreateFont(BinPath + @"Fonts\mangalb.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfnimodmt, 12);
Chunk c1 = new Chunk(HTML, font);
Phrase p1 = new Phrase(c1);
Paragraph ph = new Paragraph();
ph.Add(p1);
iTextSharp.text.Font fonts = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfnimodmt, (float)fontSize);
iTextSharp.text.Font fontsbold = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfnimodmt, (float)fontSize);

BaseFont bfnimodmta = BaseFont.CreateFont(BinPath + @"Fonts\mangal.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font fonts1 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfnimodmt, (float)fontSize);
iTextSharp.text.Font fontsbold1 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfnimodmt, (float)fontSize);
//For Image-------------------------------------------------Image------------------------------
#region For image

string imageURL = imageDynamicPath;
string FrameImgPath = Server.MapPath("~") + @"Images\big.jpg";

System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageURL);
System.Drawing.Image img2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FrameImgPath);

String jpg3 = Server.MapPath("~") + @"Images\big1.jpg";
Bitmap template = new Bitmap(img2);
Bitmap Picture = new Bitmap(img1);
iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
jpg.ScaleAbsolute(80f, 80f);
//Framejpg.ScaleAbsolute(85f, 85f);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(jpg);
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
#endregion
string strFirst, strSecond;
string HTMLinput = HTML;
int FirstEnter = HTMLinput.IndexOf("\r\n");
int FirstSpace = HTMLinput.IndexOf(" ");
int firstLINE = HTMLinput.IndexOf("</p>");
if (FirstSpace == -1 && FirstEnter == -1)
{
    strFirst = HTMLinput;
    strSecond = "";
}
else
{
    if (FirstSpace == -1)
    {
        strFirst = HTMLinput.Substring(0, HTMLinput.IndexOf("\r\n"));
        strSecond = HTMLinput.Substring(HTMLinput.IndexOf("\r\n"));
    }
    else if (FirstEnter == -1)
    {
        strFirst = HTMLinput.Substring(0, HTMLinput.IndexOf(" "));
        strSecond = HTMLinput.Substring(HTMLinput.IndexOf(" "));
    }
    else if (FirstSpace > FirstEnter)
    {
        strFirst = HTMLinput.Substring(0, HTMLinput.IndexOf("\r\n"));
        strSecond = HTMLinput.Substring(HTMLinput.IndexOf("\r\n"));
    }
    else //if (FirstSpace < FirstEnter )
    {
        strFirst = HTMLinput.Substring(0, HTMLinput.IndexOf(" "));
        strSecond = HTMLinput.Substring(HTMLinput.IndexOf(" "));
    }
}
Chunk ch = new Chunk(strFirst.ToUpper());
string seperator = "", strThid = "";
Chunk ch1 = new Chunk(strSecond);
Chunk ch2 = new Chunk(strThid);
Chunk ch3 = new Chunk(seperator);
iTextSharp.text.Paragraph prText = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(" ");
prText.Leading = 1;
List<IElement> objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLinput), null);
foreach (IElement element in objects)
{
    pageSize.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(255, 222, 173);
    document.Add(element);
    break;
}
int remove = Math.Min(objects.Count, 1);
objects.RemoveRange(0, remove);
foreach (IElement element in objects)
{
    document.Add(element);
}
document.Close();

return true;
```

In above code "myTable" is not visible in my PDF "document"

Comment: What have you tried? You did not include any code. Nor did you include an iText version.

Comment: I am using IText version 5.5.1

Comment: Is the `HTMLWorker` related part relevant? In particular, do you intend to create the tables for which you want background color also in the HTML? Or is it just some generic content?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iText7, you should be able to solve this with the following code:

```
    Table table = new Table(5);

    Cell sn = new Cell(2, 1).add("S/N");
    sn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    table.addCell(sn);

    Cell name = new Cell(1, 3).add("Name");
    name.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    ...
```

You can also have a look at the tutorials on tables
https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-adding-background-table

If you are using iText5, check out
https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/adding-background-table

If you are starting a new project with iText, consider using iText7. As iText5 is on its way to not being supported anymore.

Comment: This code is not working, I am using IText version 5.5.1

Comment: Your question did not originally include that information. I can not be expected to guess which version you are using. If you had provided code, I would have been able to tell.

Answer (score 1):

To create tables with individual cell backgrounds with iText 5.x for .Net you can use the `BackgroundColor` cell property:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell A"));
cell1.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.YELLOW;
table.AddCell(cell1);
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell B"));
cell2.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GREEN;
table.AddCell(cell2);
```

[This very old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6405623/1729265) shows the analogous approach for iText for Java.

---

For more control, e.g. for a multiple colors in the same cell, you should use a cell event, e.g. use this event class

```
public class ColorizeBackgroundEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    BaseColor color;
    public ColorizeBackgroundEvent(BaseColor color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        canvas.SaveState();
        canvas.SetColorFill(color);
        canvas.Rectangle(position.Left, position.Bottom, position.Width, position.Height);
        canvas.Fill();
        canvas.RestoreState();
    }
}
```

for the equivalent effect as above with this code:

```
using (Stream output = new FileStream(@"TableWithColoredCellBackgrounds.pdf", FileMode.Create))
using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25))
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
    document.Open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell A"));
    cell1.CellEvent = new ColorizeBackgroundEvent(BaseColor.YELLOW);
    table.AddCell(cell1);
    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell B"));
    cell2.CellEvent = new ColorizeBackgroundEvent(BaseColor.GREEN);
    table.AddCell(cell2);
    document.Add(table);

    document.Close();
}
```

The result in either case looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For a more interesting example of cell event usage look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46936653/1729265) - it's for iText for Java but should be easy to port to .Net.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31087672/1729265) also shows the usage of the `BackgroundColor` cell property.